# Converting fetchedResultsController into NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using (SOMessaging) https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/SOMessaging

I want to use this code with core datas fetchedResultsController

The problem is when implementing the messagesViewController code above you must return an NSarray of messages like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.myImage      = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arturdev.jpg"];
    self.partnerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"jobs.jpg"];


    [self loadMessages];
}

- (void)loadMessages
{
    self.dataSource = [[[ContentManager sharedManager] generateConversation] mutableCopy];
}



- (NSMutableArray *)messages
{
    return self.dataSource;
}
- (void)configureMessageCell:(SOMessageCell *)cell forMessageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    SOMessage *message = self.dataSource[index];

    // Adjusting content for 3pt. (In this demo the width of bubble's tail is 3pt)
    if (!message.fromMe) {
        cell.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 3.0f, 0, 0); //Move content for 3 pt. to right
        cell.textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    } else {
        cell.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 3.0f); //Move content for 3 pt. to left
        cell.textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    cell.userImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.userImageSize.width/2;

    // Fix user image position on top or bottom.
    cell.userImageView.autoresizingMask = message.fromMe ? UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin : UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

    // Setting user images
    cell.userImage = message.fromMe ? self.myImage : self.partnerImage;
}



The example calls this function to generate sample messages:

- (NSArray *)generateConversation
{
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Conversation" ofType:@"plist"]]];


    for (NSDictionary *msg in data) {
        SOMessage *message = [[SOMessage alloc] init];
        message.fromMe = [msg[@"fromMe"] boolValue];
        message.text = msg[@"message"];
        message.type = [self messageTypeFromString:msg[@"type"]];
        message.date = [NSDate date];

        int index = (int)[data indexOfObject:msg];
        if (index > 0) {
            SOMessage *prevMesage = result.lastObject;
            message.date = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:((index % 2) ? 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 : 120) sinceDate:prevMesage.date];
        }

        if (message.type == SOMessageTypePhoto) {
            message.media = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:msg[@"image"]], 1);
        } else if (message.type == SOMessageTypeVideo) {
            message.media = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:msg[@"video"] ofType:@"mp4"]];
            message.thumbnail = [UIImage imageNamed:msg[@"thumbnail"]];
        }

        [result addObject:message];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Meaning all messages in the message array have to be SOMessage objects.

I want to use core data so im going to be using fetchedResultsController How can I load my data into this from a fetchedresultscontroller.

I dont really want to start converting to an NSarray because im not sure what will happen when more data is added and data is reloaded.

Would be great if you could give me some code examples to help out.

If you want to see the full code its available on github so you can see how it all works.

Comment: The other problem is that the messagesController thingy is using the messages array to calculate the row height and do all the fancy stuff so I dont want to have to rip out the messages array and replace all of it with something else. :/

Comment: I am also using SOMessage.Can u let me know how can i add images/videos in the example.